# How to change the background color with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, background-color

I'm trying to make a game with Sprite Kit in Swift but I have a little problem with the background color.

I started a new project on Xcode and selected the "game" presets and Sprite Kit.
So I have the starter project with a grey background with "Hello World" in white and spaceships that appear when I press on the screen.

So I removed all the code that I don't care about but when I launch the game, I still have the grey background, even if I try to change it in the GameScene.swift file.

Here is my files:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
{

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
  }

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
  }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
  }

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
  }

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
  }

}
```

GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene
{
  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
  {
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
  }

  override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval)
  {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
  }
}
```

GameViwController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController
{

  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool
  {
    return true
  }
}
```

So how to set the background in white?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not change because you are trying to change background color if `GameScene` which is not loaded by `GameViewController` because you remove that code.

So add this code in your `GameViewController.swift`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // load your GameScene
    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

After that it will work fine.

Comment: It works thank's ! It seems to be a very stupid error but I am new to Sprite Kit and Swift, so thank's !

Comment: Happy to help you..:)